# Error while writing Txt Tile

Tags: c, file-io, network-programming

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<unistd.h>
    #include<arpa/inet.h>
    #include<sys/socket.h>

    #define BUF_SIZE 1024       
    #define OPSZ     4        //Bye of int


    void error_handling(char *message);
    int calculate(int opnds[], char  operator, char *message, char * address);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        int serv_sock, clnt_sock;
        int recv_cnt, recv_len;
        int opnd_cnt;
        char opinfo[BUF_SIZE];           
        int result;

        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr;
        socklen_t clnt_addr_size;

        FILE *getFile=fopen("data.txt", "r");
        FILE *writeFile=fopen(argv[1], "w");

        char  buffer[BUF_SIZE]={0,};

        fscanf(getFile, "%s", buffer);
        buffer[BUF_SIZE-1] = 0;

        if(argc!=3)
        {
            printf("Usage : %s <TEXT> <port>\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }

        if( (fprintf(writeFile, "%s", buffer)) == -1 )      //ERROR!!!       //Copy message to output.txt
            error_handling("fprintf ERROR! ");
        printf("%s\n\n", buffer);

        printf("Server Running...\n");

        serv_sock=socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if(serv_sock == -1)
            error_handling("socket() error");

        memset(&serv_addr, 0, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
        serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[2]));

        if(bind(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1)
            error_handling("bind() error");

        if(listen(serv_sock, 5) == -1 )
            error_handling("listen() error");

        clnt_addr_size=sizeof(clnt_addr);

        while(1)            //Iterative Server implement
            {

            recv_len = 0;           

            clnt_sock=accept(serv_sock, (struct sockaddr*) &clnt_addr,                 &clnt_addr_size);
            if(clnt_sock == -1)
                error_handling("accept() error");


            while( (3*OPSZ) > recv_len )
            {
                recv_cnt = read(clnt_sock, &opinfo[recv_len], BUF_SIZE-1);
                recv_len += recv_cnt;
    }

            result = calculate((int*)opinfo, opinfo[recv_len-1], buffer, argv[1]);
            printf("%d", result);   
            write(clnt_sock, (char*)&result, sizeof(result));


            close(clnt_sock);
        }

        close(serv_sock);

        printf("Server Closed \n ");

        fclose(getFile);
        return 0;
    }

    void error_handling(char *buffer)
    {
        fputs(buffer, stderr);
        fputc('\n', stderr);
        exit(1);
    }

    int calculate(int opnds[] ,char operator, char *buffer, char *address)
    {
        int result;
        int i;
        FILE *my_write, *my_append;
        my_write = fopen(address, "w");
        my_append = fopen(address, "a");

        switch(operator)
        {
        case '+':
            result = opnds[1] + opnds[2];
            fprintf(my_append, "%d", result);
            break;
        case '-':
            result = opnds[1] - opnds[2];
            fprintf(my_write, "%d", result);
            break;
        case '*':
            result = opnds[1] * opnds[2];
            fprintf(stdout, "%s\n" ,buffer);
            fprintf(stdout, "%d\n", result);
            break;
        }
        return result;

        fclose(my_write);
        fclose(my_append);
    }
```

I got error from the Line I wrote "ERROR" I don't know what's wrong in the Line.

I intended to write file "argv[1]". I founded that the file is created.. 
But, String in the buffer didn't sent to the File.. and it also happened in the "calculate" Fuction.

why I can't write to the file...

Comment: I suspect [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/perror.html) rather than your error handler sending some buffer to `stderr` may prove educational.

Comment: I like how you use argv[1] before you check argc...

Comment: sorry... I am learning

Comment: The code should check the return value from `fopen`. A `NULL` pointer is returned if there is an error.

Comment: what is the filename you are passing as argv[1]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities for your problem.

The first is here:

```
fscanf(getFile, "%s", buffer);
buffer[BUF_SIZE-1] = 0;
```

This code isn't wrong, it could just be a little bit dangerous because it depends on the file being plaintext and having words separated by whitespace, and that those words are shorter than the allocated buffer.  If you notice, fscanf doesn't ask for your buffer size, so you could overrun your buffer if your not careful (which can terrifically screw up everything).  Now, none of this is likely to be you problem because of your buffer size (1024)

The most likely candidate is this line here:

```
FILE *writeFile=fopen(argv[1], "w");
```

As mentioned in the comments, you haven't checked that argv[1] even exists (although it does because you check to make sure you have 3 arguments later in your code, this should be one of the first things you do)  More importantly, argv[1] is a file you are writing to.  fopen will create this file in write mode, but only if it can/needs to.  argv[1] could refer to a file your program does not have permissions to, a file locked by another program or a file in a directory that does not exists.

Thankfully, all these problems can be summed up with this simple test:

```
if(writeFile == NULL)
    error_handling("\'writeFile\' could not be opened!");
```

fopen will return a NULL pointer in the event that the specified file could not be opened.  Simply check your file pointer to see if the file was opened correctly.  This, by the way, is good practice any time opening a file in any language.

Comment: oh.. thanks.. I changed source to what you mentioned but it is still same and error message doesn't shown..

Comment: So that means that you are opening a file.  Try two things, one, printf the buffer before writing it to the file to see if you have a good buffer.  Second, replace "fprintf(writeFile, "%s", buffer)" with "fprintf(writeFile, "Testing output")", this should help you narrow down the problem

Comment: Thanks.. I solved problem. it was because of "writeFile" never meet fclose(writeFile). so it doesn't sent at all..